# Preallocate vector for write in tree recursion

Tags: r, performance, recursion, memory, vector

Consider this simple tree recursion

```
tree.recursion <- function(n)
    if (n == 0) {
        numeric(0)
    } else if (n %% 2 == 0) {
        c(tree.recursion(n / 2),
          tree.recursion(n / 2))
    } else {
        c(tree.recursion(n %/% 2),
          n,
          tree.recursion(n %/% 2))
    }

(ans <- tree.recursion(42))
```

A benchmark shows `c` takes a lot of time to execute, so I tried another version which uses `list`, but this time `unlist` becomes my bottleneck. I guess the issue lies in R's memory management.

```
tree.recursion <- function(n)
    if (n == 0) {
        numeric(0)
    } else if (n %% 2 == 0) {
        list(tree.recursion(n / 2),
             tree.recursion(n / 2))
    } else {
        list(tree.recursion(n %/% 2),
             n,
             tree.recursion(n %/% 2))
    }

(ans <- unlist(tree.recursion(42)))
```

Since you can tell the return value would be of length 42, can we just preallocate a `numeric(42)` and write to it without creating new objects? Note that a similar function is a hotspot in my real-world application, so I don't mind if you have to use some dirty hack to make it faster.

Comment: are your numbers all integers?

Comment: @GradaGukovic No, but they are all numeric.

Comment: sorry but i do not see the bottleneck, can you specify a case where it is apparent?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I do not see `c` as bottleneck. But in this exact case we can get results faster by not calling duplicated parts 2 times. Also, `numeric(0)` can be replaced just by `NULL`.

```
tree.recursion3 <- function(n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return(NULL)
  } else {
    if (n %% 2 == 0) {
      x <- tree.recursion3(n / 2)
      return(c(x, x))
    } else {
      y <- tree.recursion3(n %/% 2)
      return(c(y, n, y))
    }
  }
}

p <- 2e6
system.time(x1 <- tree.recursion(p)) # 4.5 - 5.2
system.time(x2 <- unlist(tree.recursion2(p))) # 6 - 7.8
system.time(x3 <- tree.recursion3(p)) # 0.04
all.equal(x1, x2) # TRUE
all.equal(x1, x3) # TRUE
```